# ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIEN Error With google forms API

Tags: node.js, google-api, discord.js, google-api-nodejs-client, google-forms-api

Currently trying to setup a watch in a node.js app with the google forms api. I'm recieving an error stating that I have insufficient permissions to access the form. The error I am getting is here:

```
[
  {
    '@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo',
    reason: 'ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT',
    domain: 'googleapis.com',
    metadata: {
      method: 'google.apps.forms.v1.FormsService.CreateWatch',
      service: 'forms.googleapis.com'
    }
  }
]
```

And the following is my code:

```
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
async function authenticateImplicitWithAdc() {
  const storage = new Storage({
    projectId,
  });
  const [buckets] = await storage.getBuckets();
  console.log('Buckets:');

  for (const bucket of buckets) {
    console.log(`- ${bucket.name}`);
  }

  console.log('Listed all storage buckets.');
}
const projectId = '-';


const google = require('googleapis').google;
const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
  scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/forms']
});
const formId = '1FAIpQLSfmoFbMA-qGs9LuPmBm0XMw1jGUzsDMm-Vv1jrMiyqaYvW5WQ'
const targetUrl = 'https://discord.com/api/webhooks/1092763536461148165/qh8wWVf0g9rSnmqkIB5I7gBEAzxvIAfrt2xTyszzQopyEzh6RPzio1x0i7JCS2OT-dbQ'


authenticateImplicitWithAdc();
async function createWatch() {
  const forms = google.forms({ version: 'v1', auth });
  const response = await forms.forms.watches.create({
    formId: formId,
    requestBody: {
      target: {
        url: targetUrl
      },
      eventType: 'RESPONSE'
    }
  });
  console.log(`Created watch with ID: ${response.data.id}`);
}

client.on('ready', async() => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
    client.user.setActivity(`over QLDRP members`, { type: ActivityType.Watching });
    try {
    await createWatch();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Error creating watch: ${error}`);
    console.error(error)
    console.log(error.response.data.error.details)
  }
   
});
```

Any help would be great. I have already configured an ADC as well with google cloud CLI.

Edit:

I have changed the scopes to this:

```
const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
  scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
});
```

And this is still the error:

```
[
  {
    '@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo',
    reason: 'ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT',
    domain: 'googleapis.com',
    metadata: {
      service: 'forms.googleapis.com',
      method: 'google.apps.forms.v1.FormsService.CreateWatch'
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

The method [forms.watches.create](https://developers.google.com/forms/api/reference/rest/v1beta/forms.watches/create) Requires one of the following scopes.

[image]

From what I can see you are only using `"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/forms"` Which as the message states is ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT.  As that scope only gives you access to `"View and manage your forms in Google Drive"`

Comment: I have updated the original post. Basically I adjusted the scopes to what you suggested and it still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem with your function is that it does not have the correct OAuth scope for accessing the deployments of a script project. According to the documentation, the scope for this operation is https://www.googleapis.com/auth/forms. You need to include this scope in your script project manifest file (appsscript.json) and in your OAuth consent screen. You also need to reset the authorization of your script and grant the new scope.

Here is how you can do that:

•  Open your script project in the Apps Script editor.

•  Click on Project Settings (the gear icon) and check the box for "Show appsscript.json manifest file in editor".

•  Open the appsscript.json file and look for the "oauthScopes" property. If it does not exist, add it as an array. If it exists, make sure it contains the https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.deployments scope. For example, your file might look like this:

{
"timeZone": "America/New_York",
"dependencies": {
},
"exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
"runtimeVersion": "V8",
"oauthScopes": [
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/forms",
// add any other scopes you need here
]
}

•  Save the file and close it.

•  Click on Deploy > New Deployment and create a new deployment of your script project. Copy the deployment ID and use it in your function.

•  Click on Deploy > Manage Deployments and select your new deployment. Click on View Execution API Permissions and review the scopes. Make sure they match the ones in your appsscript.json file.

•  Click on Review Permissions and grant access to your account. You might see a warning screen saying "This app isn't verified". Click on Advanced and then Go to ... (unsafe).

•  After granting access, run your function again and see if it works.